# Extra spaces in bib entries marked with langid=otherlanguage

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, polyglossia

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,autolang=other,language=autobib]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\clearfield{pagetotal}}

  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{plbook,
  author        = {Kowalski, Jan},
  title         = {Witamy w krainie czarów},
  location      = {Warszawa},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
@book{enbook,
  editor        = {Doe, John},
  title         = {Math},
  location      = {London},
  date          = {2020},
  pagetotal     = {300},
  langid        = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
f\autocite[3]{plbook}
f\autocite[3]{enbook}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is my current setup (case 1). It produces extra space after date.

I've also tried some other setups just in testing purposes and every time I get spuriuos spaces in entries which are marked with `langid = {other_language}` (tested with `langid={lithuanian,russian,english}`) while main document language is polish.

Cases:
with `\clearfield{pagetotal}`:

1. `language=autobib` - extra space after date
2. `language=auto` - extra space after cited page number

without `\clearfield{pagetotal}`:

3. `language=autobib` - extra space after pagetotal
4. `language=auto` - extra space after cited page number

Results:
[image: extraspaces]

Am I doing something wrong or it is rather a bug in `polyglossia` or `biblatex`?

UPD:
System: TexLive2022
Biblatex: 3.18
Biber: 2.18
Polyglossia: 1.56
Compiled with LuaLaTeX

Comment: looks ok here. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Abolutely yes. I have TexLive2022 with all updates. Perhaps it matters - document is compiled with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: show the log-file of your example.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ZJ0V3o

Comment: I can reproduce the undesirable space from the first image. With `babel` things look fine, so a `polyglossia` issue or `polyglossia` compatibility issue seems likely.

Comment: @moewe could you look into the chat (unrelated to this here)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Will do once I've sorted this.

Comment: @moewe The first example is the most important because this is my actual setup. Did you check other cases? Or you mean that an extra space occurs only in first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `%` in LuaTeX branch of the definition of `\polish@vlna` in `gloss-polish.ldf`. See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/pull/550.

While you wait for the fix to be released to CTAN the following definition should avoid the undesirable space. Note that this definition works for LuaLaTeX only. I did not copy the definition for XeLaTeX and the test.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

%\usepackage[english,polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,autolang=other,language=autobib]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\clearfield{pagetotal}}

\makeatletter
\def\polish@vlna{%
  \singlechars{polish}{AaIiOoUuWwZz}%
  \preventsingleon}
\makeatother
  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{plbook,
  author        = {Kowalski, Jan},
  title         = {Witamy w krainie czarów},
  location      = {Warszawa},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
@book{enbook,
  editor        = {Doe, John},
  title         = {Math},
  location      = {London},
  date          = {2020},
  pagetotal     = {300},
  langid        = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
f\autocite[3]{plbook}
f\autocite[3]{enbook}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Jan Kowalski, Witamy w krainie czarów, Warszawa, 1953, s. 3. 2 John Doe, ed., Math, London, 2020, s. 3.]

Comment: I looked at the bibliography and not the footnotes ;-(. That also explains why you get a different sorting.